# Recommendation for a book on "expressive" PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, agile, intentional-programming

Let me be clear - I have more than enough "references" and "for beginners" books.

What I want is something like "Exceptional PL/SQL" or "Agile PL/SQL" or "PL/SQL Design Patterns" or even just "PL/SQL For Developers Who Want To Write Pretty Code".

Does such a thing exist?

(I'm a C++/Ruby/etc. developer. I've been thrown into an Oracle project. The language makes me feel like my hands are tied behind my back and there's a burlap bag over my head. It's bringing back bad memories of DBase and Clipper...)

Comment: pl/sql... expressive....   .... no, I'm not following you, sorry...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this book useful:

[Oracle PL/SQL Best Practices](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596514105/)

And there are a bunch of other books by O'Reilly that might be useful to you [here](http://oreilly.com/pub/topic/oracle).

Also, if I could recommend something to read, I would suggest an Oracle performance book.  So many avoidable performance issues are often introduced by people new to PL/SQL.

Comment: +1: particularly for the performance recommendation.

Comment: Thanks for the O'Reilly book - I had just started into it. It's *approaching* what I'm looking for, though I'm realizing I'm just going to have to live with my hands tied, burlap bag, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Bit of a wildcard, but in my opinion it is worth looking at the  [presentations](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:8:343705894029744::NO) that Tom Kyte makes available.

Granted they lose something if you weren't at the presentation but ones like [SQL Techniques](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/z?p_url=ASKTOM%2Edownload_file%3Fp_file%3D2348427824846265023&p_cat=SQLTechniques.zip&p_company=822925097021874) may save you writing a ton of PL/SQL code.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks! I haven't read all the way through the .ppt in the SQLTechniques archive - I got sidetracked by the reference to one of Tom's books. Effective Oracle By Design has a chapter on PL/SQL (and a lot of other good stuff too). Worth looking at for sure.

(As is an O'Reilly Safari account!)

Answer (score 2):

Connor McDonald is a very good Oracle developer, and his book "Mastering Oracle PL/SQL" has some nice ideas/approaches.  Many of the Gang of Four's structural patterns are directly applicable: facade, proxy, adapter, bridge.

Then go to asktom.oracle.com and click on "Resources" and "Links" at the top of the page.  Tom Kyte's books are *very* good.

Comment: That Mastering Oracle PL/SQL also looks like a good one, although Safari doesn't have it. :/

Answer (score 2):

Not just PL/SQL but Oracle in general - two good books by Thomas Kyte:

[http://www.amazon.com/Expert-One-One-Oracle-Thomas/dp/1590592433](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592433)

[http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Oracle-Design-Osborne-ORACLE/dp/0072230657](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592433)